# Return type is different when invoking the same method on different objects

Tags: scala, collections

I wrote the following application:

```
  var counters: mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, Long]] = mutable.Map()
  counters("key1") = mutable.Map("counters_key"→ 20)
  counters("key2") = mutable.Map("counters_key" → 920)
  counters("key3") = mutable.Map("counters_key" → 920)
  counters("key4") = mutable.Map("counters_key" → 920)
  counters("key5") = mutable.Map("counters_key" → 920)

  var counters2: mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, Long]] = mutable.Map()
  counters2("key1") = mutable.Map("counters2_key_1"→ 112000, "counters_key_2" → 1112000, "counters_key_3"→ 20)
  counters2("key2") = mutable.Map("counters2_key_4" → 9112000, "counters_key_5" → 91112000, "counters_key_6" → 920)

  val flattenedCounters =  counters.toMap.values.flatten
  val flattenedCounters2 = counters2.toMap.values.flatten

  println(flattenedCounters.getClass == flattenedCounters2.getClass) 
  //true

  println(flattenedCounters.groupBy(_._1).getClass == 
          flattenedCounters2.groupBy(_._1).getClass) 
  //false
```

[***DEMO***](https://ideone.com/HQbBqy)

We are invoking the same method on the 2 objects which are of the same type. But it gives us objects of different types. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is in the size of counters

```
   val map = counters.toMap
   println(map.getClass)
   //class scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap
   println(map.size)
   //5

   val map2 = counters2.toMap
   println(map2.getClass)
   //class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2
   println(map2.size)
   //2
```

Looks like Scala has several implementations for `Map`. `Map2` is optimized to hold exactly 2 elements. And there are optimized implementations up to `Map4`

You can find those classes in [sources](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/79e5101738d5b4675ab4194d6c18d443a496ef7c/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L130)

When you call `toMap` it creates new builder that holds empty map.
Then for each element adds it to the map.

- Empty map + new key is Map1 [src](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/79e5101738d5b4675ab4194d6c18d443a496ef7c/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L103)
- Map1 + new key is Map2 [src](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/79e5101738d5b4675ab4194d6c18d443a496ef7c/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L120)
- ...
- Map4 + new key is HashMap [src](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/79e5101738d5b4675ab4194d6c18d443a496ef7c/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L224)

Comment: Very interesting... The actual type depends on the number of element. [This deme](https://ideone.com/Pm9qka) still shows the difference. But [this one](https://ideone.com/ZAA5fg) return the same result... Still a bit unclear how is that possible.

Comment: Added more references to sources

Comment: @NazariiBardiuk 's list then continues in [immutable.HashMap](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.scala), which includes `HashMap1`, `HashTrieMap` and `HashMapCollision`, which in turn cover a slightly greater range of "small" immutable maps. The philosophy is actually simple: *treat small collections differently*. They can give you a different version for every size, because of polymorphism. If you want to know the gory details, you must read the linked sources. It's not a pleasant read, that's for sure. (+) for Nazarii for research effort

Comment: Very interesting research! Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Nazarii Bardiuk, it's due to the difference in the immutable Map size.  Scala optimizes small Maps by storing them as single objects with elements as fields and implements larger Maps as [HashMap](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.scala), which uses `HashTrieMap`.

Here's quote under section `Hash Tries` from a relevant [Scala doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html):

> Scala has a further optimization for immutable sets and maps that
>   contain less than five elements. Sets and maps with one to four
>   elements are stored as single objects that just contain the elements
>   (or key/value pairs in the case of a map) as fields.